# Running multiple streams in same thread

Tags: rx-java

Is it possible subscribe two different streams in a same thread other than caller thread?

Suppose that I have two different observables and two different subscribers. And I call `subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())` on both observables. But I want them subscribe on same thread, not two different threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
Scheduler scheduler = 
    Schedulers.from(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());
```

Then apply `.subscribeOn(scheduler)` to both observables. One stream could block the other stream but this will depend of course on your observables and the subscriber request patterns.

Answer (score 1):

In short, no.  There are some hacks that you could try but they would be problematic.  It's best to use multiple threads.

Comment: Is there anything problematic with Dave Moten's answer?